# Image gallery in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently working on an image gallery (or products with their images) and am getting a weird error in the UploadImageMethod in my ProductsController. Here's the method, then I'll explain where the error is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImageMethod()
{
    //make sure we have files to upload
    if (Request.Files.Count != 0)
    {
        //Parallel.For loop to loop through each image being uploaded
        Parallel.For(0, Request.Files.Count, index =>
            {
                //new HttpPostedFileBase to hold each image with
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[index];

                //get the file size
                int size = file.ContentLength;

                //get the file name
                string name = file.FileName;

                //save the image to our desired directory
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/ProductImages/") + name);

                //now create a new Product and set it's properties
                Product p = new Product()
                {
                    ProductId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    ProductName = name,
                    ProductImages.Add(new ProductImage() { Path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/ProductImages/") + name, AltText = name })
                };

                //add it to the database
                db.Products.Add(p);

                //save the changes
                db.SaveChanges();
            });
        return Content("Success");
    }
    return Content("failed");
}
}
```

I'm getting the error on this line:

```
ProductImages.Add(new ProductImage() { Path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/ProductImages/") + name, AltText = name })
```

It says "invalid initializer member declarator" , it also says ProductImages does not exist in the current context. If you need to see the Product class here it is:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        ProductImages = new List<ProductImage>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

When I do it this way I get no errors

```
var p = new Product();

    p.ProductId = Guid.NewGuid();
    p.ProductName = name;
    p.ProductImages.Add(new ProductImage() { Path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/ProductImages/") + name, AltText = name });
```

Anyone have an explanation for this for me?

Answer (score 0):

try this  image galary in mvc

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b696c4/creating-image-gallery-in-mvc-5-application631/

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/12/create-image-photo-gallery-in-aspnet-mvc-in-jquery-using-csharp.html